# Accessing build.gradle ext at run time

Tags: android, gradle

Does anyone know how to access something that I have in my build.gradle file at runtime?

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        exoplayerVersion = "2.8.2"
    }
}
```

I'd like to grab that 2.8.2 value at runtime, but I can't figure out how to do it. Thanks for any help.

Comment: By run time, you mean inside the mobile application?

Comment: In the code of my app, I want to add a line that can return the string "2.8.2" such that even if that string is ever changed in the future, I will always get the most recent string.

Comment: have you considered creating custom application.properties?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`buildConfigField`](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-tips#share-custom-fields-and-resource-values-with-your-app-code).

Sample declaration (taken from the official docs) :

```
android {
  ...
  buildTypes {
    release {
      // These values are defined only for the release build, which
      // is typically used for full builds and continuous builds.
      buildConfigField("String", "BUILD_TIME", "\"${minutesSinceEpoch}\"")
      resValue("string", "build_time", "${minutesSinceEpoch}")
      ...
    }
    debug {
      // Use static values for incremental builds to ensure that
      // resource files and BuildConfig aren't rebuilt with each run.
      // If they were dynamic, they would prevent certain benefits of
      // Instant Run as well as Gradle UP-TO-DATE checks.
      buildConfigField("String", "BUILD_TIME", "\"0\"")
      resValue("string", "build_time", "0")
    }
  }
}
...
```

Usage:

```
...
Log.i(TAG, BuildConfig.BUILD_TIME);
```

**Update:**

You can NOT access `ext` properties in Java code. Just for completeness of the answer, you can use these properties in other gradle files in your project.

Comment: I don't think that this will work for me as it would require other modifications to my build.gradle file, which I cannot do.

Comment: cannot do as in? You don't have access to your build.gradle?

Comment: I have access, but do not have the authority to change it.

Comment: No problem. If this gave you a definitive answer, you should accept it so that it helps other people landing on this question in future.

Answer (score 0):

The answer that @Yashasvi provided is correct however if your use case is as you described (getting a version of a library in code) I would first suggest to look into the APIs of the library and see if there is any notion of version in there. That is for example what `Build.VERSION.SDK_INT` provide us for android version. if not here is more tailored answer for your specific question:

```
android {
    ...
    buildTypes {
        release {
            ...

            buildConfigField("String", "exoplayerVersion", exoplayerVersion)
        }
        debug {
            ...

            buildConfigField("String", "exoplayerVersion", exoplayerVersion)
        }
    }
}
```

And then you can find a reference to that String in your BuildConfig file like this (this file gets generated on each build so make sure you compile the app after adding the field or making changes to it in order to see the changes):

```
BuildConfig.exoplayerVersion
```